# Why use Xaml markup in Xamarin.Forms projects if i can do all job in C# file?

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

Why I should use Xaml markup in Xamarin.Forms projects if I can do all job in C# file? I think about this a lot time. I did not find answer about that in Google search. I think with C# I can do my apps faster than with using Xaml. Maybe someone know something fundamental about that? I'm new in Xamarin.Forms.

Comment: Mostly that it is common practice to separate the logic layer and the ui layer. Also I know in VS you can visually create the ui and edit it at design time if you make it in xaml, which isn't possible in just code.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Advantages of UI design in XAML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1536244/advantages-of-ui-design-in-xaml)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why i should use Xaml markup in

It is easier to express *visual* coding patterns in `Xaml` as templates than to attempt it in code. Once a template is defined, say within a list, the data it represents will be repeated for each data item based on that one template.

It appears easier for you to code it, because I surmise you are now learning about Xaml and *getting it working* is the more important.

The rule of thumb is that Xaml specified should define a *bare* framework and the data will fill in that framework. By doing it in Xaml it can be created and more importantly updated using the `Xaml` design view (editor) to achieve the end goal.

Comment: Xaml with Resharper makes things much easier I have to admit. Unfortunately some things aren't possible (or are much harder) with XAML so I still do almost half of the pages in code.

Comment: @SKall hopefully with MS purchasing Xamarin, the process will be more favorable to Xaml design surface such as WPF or even *Silverlight* going foward. ;-)